# breezejs: inlineCount is incorrect when sorting by navigation property

Tags: javascript, breeze

I'm using the latest version of breeze. This has fixed the bug of the inlineCount not returned when sorting by navigation property.

However, the inlineCount is incorrect when sorting by navigation property.

Consider the following ODATA request:

```
http://myserver/api/mandates/Mandates?$orderby=AccountOwner%2FTiersId%20desc&$top=1&$inlinecount=allpages
```

The sort is on a navigation property called AccountOwner.TiersId and it should return ten results per page.

inlineCount always returns the number of records per page instead of the total number of records (in this case it should be 150, but it returns 10).

Can you fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is fixed in the current bits on GitHub. ( You can just retrieve the Breeze.WebApi.dll and you should be good to go).  We will include this fix in our next full release version (v 1.4.1) out probably sometime next week.

and thanks for finding it :)

Comment: any news on this ? when is 1.4.1 going to be released ?

Comment: Early next week, probably. :)

Comment: I got the latest version now but this bug does not seem to be fixed. I've double-checked that I'm using 1.4.1 on the client side and the version of breeze.webapi is 1.4.0.0 (as in the nuget package). InlineCount is returned with the value of page size instead of total records. Can you check ?

Comment: All of our tests for this pass with 1.4.1. Can you send a "simple" repro to breeze@ideablade.com.

Comment: arf.... I was still using the old nuget package. I don't know why sometimes nuget packages updates don't work. I have to uninstall the package and reinstall it again. Anyway this is all fixed now. Thanks !